# Show bottomSheet beneath bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

In our app we're using a bottomSheet along with a bottomNavigationBar.

The bottomSheet appears above the bottomNavigationBar, is there a way to make it appear underneath?

Here's a sample app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(SampleApp());
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleAppState createState() => new _SampleAppState();
}

class _SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  PersistentBottomSheetController _sheetController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _showBottomSheet = () {
      _sheetController = _scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet((context) {
        return Container(
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              RadioListTile(dense: true, title: Text('Test'), groupValue: 'test', onChanged: (value) {}, value: true),
              RadioListTile(dense: true, title: Text('Test'), groupValue: 'test', onChanged: (value) {}, value: true),
            ]));
      });
    };

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sample App'),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: _showBottomSheet,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is impossible. I understand what you are aiming for, but that is just an issue with the way it works generally. The new FAB positions also do not work well with the `bottomNavigationBar`. Might just check issues on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your popup with the bottom navigation bar using `Column` and simulate bottom sheet behavior using [Expandable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/expandable):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(SampleApp());
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleAppState createState() => new _SampleAppState();
}

class _SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    buildBottomSheet() {
      return Container(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
            RadioListTile(dense: true, title: Text('Test'), groupValue: 'test', onChanged: (value) {}, value: true),
            RadioListTile(dense: true, title: Text('Test'), groupValue: 'test', onChanged: (value) {}, value: true),
          ]));
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sample App'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: ExpandableNotifier(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ExpandableButton(
                child: SizedBox(height: 50,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expandable(
                expanded: buildBottomSheet(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For a production app, consider using `SafeArea` to add proper padding at the bottom.

Answer (score 16):

add : useRootNavigator: true,

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      useRootNavigator: true,
      builder: (context) {},
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is for showModalBottomSheet whereas I'd like to use showBottomSheet.

Comment: this should be the answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Noticed your question. Had same problem and found better solution. Use `showModalBottomSheet()`. It will overlay bottom navigation.

Comment: Don't get why this isn't the accepted answer. The accepted answer looks like a hacky work around and yours just works like a charm.

Comment: showModalBottomSheet overlays the entire view, also adding a barrier which prevents interaction with any view below it. There are business cases for both, however the question asked relates to `showBottomSheet`, the non-modal version.