# Flutter: Show "showBottomSheet" over "bottomNavigationBar"

Tags: flutter, user-interface

How can i display "showBottomSheet" on top of "bottomNavigationBar".

Illustrative example: when the user clicks on the pin (screen1), it turns out (screen 2), but I would like to get (screen3)

[image]

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () { 
       showBottomSheet(
           context: context,
           builder: (c) => Container(...)
       );
    },
    ...
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    ...
  ),
);
```

Comment: Add your codes first.

Comment: @OMiShah added example code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show bottomSheet beneath bottomNavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667783/show-bottomsheet-beneath-bottomnavigationbar)

Comment: @OMiShah this is not what i want(

Comment: I doubt then if there is another solution.

Answer (score 3):

> You can use
>
> ```
> showModalBottomSheet()
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> showBottomSheet()
> ```

`showModelBottomSheet()` open from bottom of your screen and overlap your bottom navigation.

Comment: I need the ability to interact with elements that are behind the `bottomSheet`. `showModalBottomSheet` - does not make it possible (

Comment: @ЖеняСкакун did you find an answer/solution for this?

Comment: @AndyShephard Yes it worked (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xh-ROfLGyMUBhH1MN1IBM8AGAoD1qBnZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I used a stack([ scaffold, stopper ]);  stopper - https://pub.dev/packages/stopper ( but I had to modify it a lot )