# How can I generate this when I press the floating action button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to generate a container or a flap (I don't know the word) when I press the floating action button, everything is explained on the screen, Thanks a lot !

[image: screen]

I am expecting this tab to generate from the bottom to the top when I press the button and then to disapear from the top to the bottom when I press the button again

Comment: Use `bottom sheet`.

Comment: With animation if possible

Comment: Yes bootm sheets has default animated opening from bottom.

Comment: Okay it might be that, thanks dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
floatingActionButton: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text('Botton 1')),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Botton 2'))
                ],
              );
            },
            context: context);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

Comment: How can I link that with my floating action button ?

Comment: I updated  my answer check it out. @Boatti

Comment: And I want to generate it from behind the nav bar, is it possible ?

Comment: one thing you can do is that put your nav bar widget at the end of column which is inside BottomSheet.

Comment: the nav bar is now in the bottom sheet this is not working

Comment: I think one have found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996161/show-bottom-modal-sheet-above-the-bottom-navigation-bar